# Unexpected color?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

So I have created some little methods to create a canvas more easily. Here's are the parts related to the unexpected result:

```
var Functions = {
    createCanvas: function (width, height) {
        ...
        return {
            ...
            line: function (obj) {
                var ctx = this.ctx;
                ctx.save();
                ctx.moveTo(obj.x, obj.y);
                ctx.lineTo(obj.a, obj.b);
                ctx.lineWidth = (obj.width || 1);
                ctx.strokeStyle = (obj.color || "black");
                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.restore();
                return this;
            },
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

This does work and it did draw a line in the correct place, but when I specify the color this way, it seems to always use the last color specified for all lines drew in chain:

```
Functions.createCanvas(100, 100).line({
    x: 10, y: 0.5,
    a: 90, b: 0.5,
    color: "blue"
}).line({
    x: 10, y: 2.5,
    a: 90, b: 2.5,
    color: "red"
});
```

The first line should be in blue; however, somehow it ends up with red.

I couldn't really find where the problem is since the first line should be drew already before the second `line()` gets called. Any idea?

Here's the whole thing: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/nzRSY/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you start your line drawing with ctx.beginPath();

```
       line: function (obj) {
            var ctx = this.ctx;
            ctx.beginPath();            // or else the next fillstyle will overwrite
            ctx.save();
            ctx.moveTo(obj.x, obj.y);
            ctx.lineTo(obj.a, obj.b);
            ctx.lineWidth = (obj.width || 1);
            ctx.strokeStyle = (obj.color || "black");
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.restore();
            return this;
        },
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works now; Didn't know `beginPath` is that important.